# mysql query only retrurning one row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the below query which I would like to retrieve all rows however, I am only getting the last row. What am I doing wrong here? I have three records in the table.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from messages");
echo $db->error;
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$test = $row['message'];
}

echo $test;
```

Comment: you are overwritting $test in the loop. `echo` inside the loop or (several alternatives)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're always overwriting the $test variable so you should put inside the while echo $test or save in an array and then print_r or var_dump that array

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$test = $row['message'];
echo $test;
}
```

or

```
$test = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $test[] = $row['message'];

    }
    print_r($test);
```

Comment: @user3006683 - Please tell the answerer what happened when you tried it - **with details**. Saying 'it doesn't work' makes it hard for people to help you.

Comment: fixed it you just missed the semicolon after `array()`

Answer (score 1):

Which row are you echoing? See that $test is written to in the loop, but you don't echo until you've finished getting the last row.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$test = $row['message'];
}

echo $test;
```

you need to put the echo in the loop

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $test = $row['message'];
    echo $test;
}
```

Comment: I need to use the rows outside the while loop also.

Comment: Please edit your question with all the details. Don't increase the scope of the question in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your *query* is retrieving all the rows - but your code to get the results is only outputting the last. You only `echo $test` once, so you're only going to get the last value that was ever assigned to it. If you want to see them all, move the `echo` inside the loop, or make it an array:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $test = $row['message'];
    echo $test;
}
```

or

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $test[] = $row['message'];
}
print_r($test);
```

Comment: why assign to $test at all in this case, just `echo  $row['message'];`

Comment: @Dagon because chances are the actual program in question wants to do more with the row than just echo it. Maintaining similarity to the example code from the OP has its uses.

Comment: but its wastfull, all those electrons killed for nothing!

Comment: @user3006683 Are you already using `$test` earlier in your code?

Answer (score 1):

To do it exactly as you want with slight modification

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from messages");
echo $db->error;
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$test = '';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
$test .= $row['message'];
}

echo $test;
```

Comment: +1 to compensate for the -1, this is a valid answer, could be the best solution, impossible to tell based on the question

Comment: @Dagon: Thanks. Performance wise. Is it better to echo five times or once?

Comment: once. but we are talking nanoseconds of savings.

Answer (score 0):

You simply overwrite $test each time in your loop, at the end it contains only the last message.